# ¿Como sumar numero de un archivo de texto?

Tags: java, archivo, interfaz-gráfica

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo un archivo de texto donde tengo la siguiente información: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de sacar los totales de las columnas Confirmed, Deaths y Recovered ya logre sacar el total de la columna Confirmed pero no he logrado sacar los demás totales no he podido, e intentado aplicar el mismo código que use para la columna de Confirmed pero no se porque no funciona llevo ya varios días intentándolo pero no lo he logrado por favor ayuda. Dejo el código donde realizo la suma de la columna confirmed:

```
 public String[] cargarDatos() {
        String[] temp = {};
        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                temp = br.readLine().split(",");
                String casos;
                if (temp.length >= 4) {
                    casos = temp[3];
                } else {
                    casos = "0";
                }
                total_c += Integer.parseInt(casos);
                if (temp.length >= 5) {
                    casos = temp[4];
                } else {
                    casos = "0";
                }

                    total_d += Integer.parseInt(casos);


            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Que quiere decir que no funciona? sale un error?

Comment: si exacto me arroja el siguiente error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Y no debe ser un entero lo que tiene tu string. Proba con tryparse

Comment: una disculpa como utilizo el tryparse

Comment: Mi error. En java no tenes tryparse. Lo que tenes que hacer es encapsular el parse. Si da error, es que no se puede convertir.